# What is your favourite Java Script WYSIWYG Editor component?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, textarea, wysiwyg

I definitifely like the one at stackoverflow, because it's clean and simple. Also the live preview with code/syntax hilighting is really helpful (and motivating).

What is your favourite Javascript Editor Framework and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [widgEditor](http://themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/) because it's    very simple and it only do the minimum. TinyMCE or FCKeditor are goods, but they are too big for what I need.

Answer (score 3):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) looks good with lots of useful features.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumpeld over [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/), which is JQuery based and adaptable for different kinds of markup.

Could be an option, if your markup isn't just HTML, but Template, Forum or "whatever style" 
markup.

I found a [List of Editors](http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/03/09/9-of-the-best-rich-text-editors-reviewed/) with their features.

Answer (score 2):

[Simple Text Editor](http://code.gosu.pl/dl/STE/demo/STE.html) is a good one ([STE 1.0](http://code.gosu.pl/dl/STE/STE.1.0.0.zip)).

Answer (score 2):

In my web-hacker days, I used [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/) quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I like [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) because of it's flexibility and it worked fine on all the browsers I've tested it on.

Comment: fck is the one I go to by default too.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on your needs, here are your options: TinyMCE, NicEdit, FreeRichTextEditor, TinyEditor, openWYSIWYG, WYMeditor, jHtmlArea, uEditor, CLEditor, jQRTE, jQuery Simple WYSIWYG Editor, xinha, ckedit

Answer (score 0):

I love [tiny_mce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Goran