# What control do I use to create an input box with different formatting

Tags: html, input, formatting, textarea, wysiwyg

I would like to create a web form with something like a text area. The user should be able to type/edit text fonts, colours, and make the text appear in various styles as they type. Also if the user draws an html table, it should appear in the box as they continue to type.

I know that there are simple text boxes and text areas in html but they don't have the above functionality. Is there some component that exists for this purpose or is it something created using one's own code like with Java?

Any inputs on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your favourite Java Script WYSIWYG Editor component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147867/what-is-your-favourite-java-script-wysiwyg-editor-component)

Comment: @Qentin, this is NOT a duplicate. I was curious to know how one could allow various formatting on a textbox/textarea. I'm a developer and I only needed the concept. I figured it out from the example in the answer. It's to use DIVs and edit them using Javascript on the fly. That's an awfully easy thing to do but I never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/

It's not a form field but with some tinkering you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: Thanks a lot... You've shown me a working example. I actually needed the concept :) It was very easy but I never thought of it like this... Thanks again!